# Forearm walking crutch and air travel

Tags: air-travel, airport-security, accessibility

Is it a problem to travel by plane with an aluminium forearm walking crutch similar to this one?

[image: crutch]

I will be traveling by plane in two days (Czech Airlines PRG-CDG). I have a minor injury. I prefer to use my crutch but I could travel without it if it meant some complications. What is the typical procedure at security scanner and on board when you carry such an item?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No problem at all, you might be asked to put it with the luggage inside the X-Ray scanner at the security check. Nothing special onboard, you will be asked to put it in an overhead bin if it fits (the crew will help you with that), or they will find a place to stow it.

Remember, you can always request assistance from the airlines, they can provide you with a wheelchair all the way to/from the gate (usually for free).

Comment: Ah ok, thanks, I wasn't 100% sure about the policies. I won't need a wheelchair, both T2 in PRG and T2D in Paris are quite small, barrier-free and close to the public transport :)

Comment: I think you mean overhead _bin_?

Comment: @pnuts I'm gladly not taking RyanAir. Anyways, the article is _very manipulative_ (what is the context of the very last sentence, for instance?) and I completely understand the decision of RyanAir.